# what is the story of Krishanu the archer?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, rig-veda

Rigveda [alludes](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04027.htm) a story where a falcon steals Soma from the heaven and gives it the Manu/Indra for sacrificial purpose. The Soma is guarded by fortification and it is protected by an archer name Krishanu. In the process of stealing, Krishanu hits the falcon by an arrow ensuing in loss of a feather of the falcon. However, the falcon succeeds in this task.

The same Krishanu fires [an arrow towards Indra and Vishnu](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01155.htm) in the famous hymn [which mentions of 90 horses of Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/what-is-the-story-of-the-90-horses-of-vishnu). Questions:

1. Do we know from later texts who was Krishanu?
2. Why did he attack Indra and Vishnu?
3. Why did the falcon steal Soma from the heaven?

Comment: Krishanu is Agni, and the falcon is Garuda.  Garuda stole the pot of Soma/Amrita from Devaloka.

Comment: In Taittreya Aryankya, Krishanu is said to be a gandharva.

Comment: In the Vedas, "Gandharva" is usually used as a name of Surya the sun god, rather than the race of celestial singers known as the Gandharvas.  I haven't seen the Taittiriya Aranyaka passage you're referring to, but it's probably connecting Agni to the sun in some way.

Comment: Third question "Why did falcon steal soma?" is the different question which should be asked separately.

Comment: @Pandya Whom are you talking to? Walls? If we want to remove, we have to remove ourselves.

Comment: Not much helpful but  this shedding some light  - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AVjSN8gcycYC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=Krishanu+vedas&source=bl&ots=zRPSSMGpKU&sig=ugv_8mZ8nvFq_5CKHagUQCxuHPs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJhdmq2qPeAhWHFogKHTuRBGUQ6AEwBHoECA8QAQ#v=onepage&q=Krishanu%20vedas&f=false