# Where is the Shanti Mantra for Sri Rudram mentioned in Scriptures (Vedas/Puranas)?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, translation-request, rudram

The Shanti Mantra for Shri Rudram is as follows:

> हरि: ॐ 
>   इडादेवहुर्मनुर्यग्न्यनिब्रुहस्पतिरुक्तथामदानि स(गुन०)सिशदविश्वेदेवा: सुक्तवाच: प्रुथिविमातर्मा मा हि(गुन०)सि: मघुमनिश्ये मघुजनिश्ये मधुवक्श्यमि मधुवदिश्यमि मधुमतिं देवेभ्यो वाचुमुद्यस्(गुन०)सुश्रूशेणयामनुशयेभ्यस्तम् मा देवा अवन्तु शोभायै पितरोनुमदन्तु॥

but I cannot find its source nor its true meaning. Please give me meaning and location in scriptures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mantra you mentioned isn't actually part of the Rudram.  The Rudram and Chamakam constitute Prapathaka 5 and Prapathaka 7 of the [Fourth Kanda](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv04.htm) of the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda.  In contrast, the mantra you're looking for is from [Prapathaka 3](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv04.htm) of the Third Kanda of the Taittiriya Samhita:

> iii.3.2
>
> vāyúr hiṃkartā́gníḥ prastotā́ prajā́patiḥ sā́ma bŕ̥haspátir udgātā́ víśve devā́ upagātā́ro marútaḥ pratihartā́ra índro nidʰánaṃ té devā́ḥ prāṇabʰŕ̥taḥ prāṇám máyi dadʰatu |
>
> etád vái sárvam adʰvaryúr upākurvánn udgātŕ̥bʰya upā́karoti té devā́ḥ prāṇabʰŕ̥taḥ prāṇám máyi dadʰatv íty āhaitád evá sárvam ātmán dʰatte |
>
> **íḍā devahū́r mánur yajñanī́s |**
>
> **bŕ̥haspátir uktʰāmadā́ni śaṁsiṣat |**
>
> **víśve devā́ḥ ||**
>
> **súktavā́cas |**
>
> **pŕ̥tʰivi mātar mā́ mā hiṁsīs |**
>
> **mádʰu maniṣye mádʰu janiṣye mádʰu vakṣyāmi mádʰu vadiṣyāmi mádʰumatīṃ devébʰyo vā́cam udyāsaṁ śuśrūṣéṇyām manuṣyèbʰyas**
>
> **tám mā devā́ avantu śobʰā́yai pitáro 'nu madantu ||**
>
> a The maker of the sound 'Him' is Vayu, the Prastotr is Agni, the
> Saman is Prajapati, the Udgatr is Brhaspati, the subordinate singers
> are the All-gods, the Pratihartrs are the Maruts, the finale is Indra;
> may these gods who support breath bestow breath upon me.
>
> b All this the Adhvaryu, as he begins, begins for the Udgatrs; 'May
> these gods who support breath bestow breath upon me', he says; verily
> he bestows all this on himself.
>
> **c May Ida who summoneth the gods, Manu who leadeth the sacrifice,**
>
> **d May Brhaspati recite the hymns and acclamations.**
>
> **e The All-gods are reciters of the hymns.**
>
> **f O earth mother, do not harm me.**
>
> **g Of honey shall I think, honey shall I produce, honey shall I
> proclaim, honey shall I speak, may I utter speech full of honey for
> the gods, and acceptable to men.**
>
> **h May the gods aid me to radiance, may the Pitrs rejoice in me.**

As you can see [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv00.htm), this mantra is one of "[t]he Mantras for beginning the Stotra and the Pratigara".  Let me explain.

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36), Yagnas generally involved three priests, a Hotri who would utter Rig Veda mantras in their original form heard from the gods, an Advaryu who would utter Yajur Veda mantras while tending to the details of the Yagna, and an Udgatri who would sing songs from the Sama Veda.  (Later a "brahmana" for the Atharvana Veda was added.)  Now as described in [this chapter](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2651.htm) of the Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda, there was a certain part of the Soma Yagna in which the Udgatri would utter a hymn called a Stotra, and in response the Hotri would utter a hymn called a Shastra, and in response to that the Adhvaryu would utter a hymn called a Pratigara.  This mantra was one of the mantras used to initiate that part of the Yagna.

The use of part of the mantra is also described in [this excerpt](http://www.dli.gov.in/data9/upload/0298/969/PTIFF/00000034.tif) from the Shankhyana Shrauta Sutras:

> In this manner having summoned (the deities) he sits down with his knees raised and mutters, after having touched the earth with the span of his right hand: "May I not be separated from this firm standing, **O Mother Earth.  Hurt me not, scorch me not.  I shall think what is sweet, wish what is sweet, engender what is sweet.  I shall today utter words sweet to Gods, dear to men.**  Here do I by means of the fifteen-fold thunderbolt drive away my spiteful rival."

So to sum up, this mantra has no connection in the Vedas to the recital of the Rudram or Chamakam.  People today may just use this as a Shanti mantra for the Chamakam because it's a mantra asking for blessings from all the gods.  It would be similar to how the "gananam" mantra is often used nowadays as an Ahavaniya mantra in Yagnas, just because you're supposed to pray to Ganesha in the beginning of rituals.  (Except the gananam mantra is not actually addressed to Ganesha, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3135/36).)

Comment: according to manusmriti we cannot recite other three Vedas when there is samagyan going on how is the system you mention of hotri etc is possible??

Comment: That Manu Smriti prohibition is about the circumstances under which you can recite the Vedas at home as part of your daily rituals.  It's not about Yagnas.

Comment: @Yogi By the way, in case, you were wondering Ida refers to Ila, the child of Vaivasvata Manu who kept changing genders.  As a man he was known as Sudyumna, and as a woman was known as Ila.  Budha, god of the planet Mercury, had a child with Ila, Pururavas founder of the lunar dynasty, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4143/36  The reason that it's called the lunar dynasty is that Budha is the son of Chandra and Tara, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3106/36

Comment: @Yogi And the reason that Vaivasvata Manu and Ila are mentioned in this mantra is to reference the Yagna performed after the flood, described in this chapter of the Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda: http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1234.htm

Comment: I thougut Ida refers to the Ida naadi the pranic channel in body

Comment: @Yogi No, the notion of Nadis is not mentioned in the Samhitas and Brahmanas of the Vedas at all.  The earliest mention of Nadis is in the Upanishads, and that too only in the later Upanishads, except for a passage in the Chandigya Upanishad that some interpret to be an allusion to Nadis.

Comment: Also can you give me photograph of the position for the "pruthivi matrmaa.." recitation because I wasn't aware about it and want to bring it to practice.... Why is it so that Vedas do not discuss Yoga, but it is still most important anga(tool) in sanatana dharma  to realize god inside us.

Comment: @Yogi "Also can you give me photograph of the position for the "pruthivi matrmaa.." recitation because I wasn't aware about it and want to bring it to practice...." Haha, I applaud your eagerness, but this isn't something you just perform by itself. It's part of the Darshapurnamasa, which is a ritual performed on the new moon day and full moon day. That ritual is more involved than just the one page that I linked to. You can read the Shankhayana Shrauta Sutra here: http://gdurl.com/4OYL/download But this is a text that's meant for those who belong to the Rig Veda, and that too not all of them.

Comment: @Yogi "Why is it so that Vedas do not discuss Yoga, but it is still most important anga(tool) in sanatana dharma to realize god inside us." First of all, when you say Yoga, do you mean Patanjali-style Ashtanga Yoga (what some people call Raja Yoga) or do you mean things like Bhakti Yoga, Jnana Yoga etc.? Patanjali Yoga isn't part of Vedanta; Vyasa actually says in the Brahma Sutras "Hereby is refuted Yoga." http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm But if you mean Jnana Yoga, etc., the Samhitas and Brahmanas are focused on Yagnas; discussion of Brahman and Jnana is left for Upanishads.

Comment: by yoga I mean to say Raja Yoga, hatha yoga, gnyana yoga, krama yoga,kriya yoga,bhakti yoga and all types of methods given for unification with supreme omnipotent god.

Comment: @Yogi The Samhitas and Brahmanas, known as the Karma Kanda of the Vedas, aren't concerned with Moksha - they're concerned with the deeds you need to do to go to Devaloka when you die, like the performance of Vedic Yagnas.  The pursuit of Moksha is left for the Jnana Kanda of the Vedas, in particular the Upanishads.  That is why the Brahma Sutras start out with "Athato Brahma Jijnasa" - after having studied the Karma Kanda of the Vedas, it is time to inquire about Brahman through the Jnana Kanda.

Answer (score 9):

It is (Shanti patha of) [**Shri Rudram Chamakam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Rudram_Chamakam) From [**Yajurveda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda)

### Where is it located in scriptures?

Yajurveda has two primary version:

1. Shukla Yajurveda,
2. Krishna Yajurveda

There are four shakha of Krishna Yajurveda

- The Taittiriya Shakha
- The Maitrayani Shakha
- The Caraka-Katha Shakha
- The Kapisthala shakha

And ***Taittiriya Shakha constitue Shri Rudram Chamakam***. (Accroding to wikipedia):

> The Taittiriya Samhita— ([TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taittiriya_Shakha)) which consists of 8 books or kaandas, subdivided in chapters or prapathakas, further subdivided into individual hymns. Some individual hymns in this Samhita have gained particular importance in Hinduism; e.g. TS 4.5 and TS 4.7 constitute the **Shri Rudram Chamakam**, while 1.8.6.i is the Shaivaite Tryambakam mantra.

---

You can see **Shri Rudram Chamakam Lyrics** at [HinduLiterature.org](http://hinduliterature.org/english/stotrams/sri_rudram_chamakam.php) in various languages.

Also from [SanskritDocuments.org](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/chamaka.html?lang=sa):

[image: screen-shot]

---

### Meaning in English translation:

From: [gloryofhinduism.blogspot.com](http://gloryofhinduism.blogspot.com/2011/03/english-translation-of-sri-rudram.html)

> **Chamakam Shanti patha**
>
> Idaa devahuurmanuryagyaniirbrihaspatirukthaamadaani
>   shasishhadvishvedevaah
>   suuktavaachah prithiviimaatarmaa maa hisiirmadhu manishhye madhu
>   janishhye madhu
>   vakshyaami madhu vadishhyaami madhumatiim devebhyo vaachamudyaasa
>   shushruushhenyaam manushhyebhyastam maa devaa avantu shobhaayai
>   pitaroanumadantu
>
> The Divine Gods are imploved through the mantras of Kamadhenu.
>   Manu does the Sacrifices, Bruhaspati recites the pleasant mantras.
>   Let these praises of Visva devas and mother earth save me from sufferance.
>   Let my pleasant thoughts bring forth pleasant actions and the resultant enjoyable fruits.
>   Let my Joyous offerings bear fine and worthy speech and my words please the divinity, make men lend their ears to gladden and Gods enlighten me and invoke my speech very powerful and my fore fathers feel excellently glad over it and bless me to perpetuate it.

There is **pdf** also available at [Here](http://cincinnatitemple.com/articles/SriRudram.pdf).