# Why is Rig Veda Book 2 Hymn 23 Verse 1 not used for summoning or praying to ganpati?

Tags: vedas, mantras, ganesha, rig-veda, vedic-gods

As mentioned in answer to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/where-is-this-hymn-in-the-rig-veda/3135?noredirect=1#comment18128_3135) question, Rig-veda verse 1 as follows

> ॐ गणानां त्वा गणपतिं हवामहे कविं कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम् ।
>
> ज्येष्ठराजं ब्रह्मणां ब्रह्मणस्पत आ नः षृण्वन्नूतिभिः सीदसादनम् ॥

cannot be used to worship Shri Ganesha. I don't understand how/why the description  of the shloka relates to Brihaspati rather than  Shri Ganesha.

If anyhow this is not the avhanam(summoning) mantra for Shri Mahaganpati then which vedic mantra is used to summon Shri Mahaganpati?. The mantra at it's end I could recite following lines.

> श्रिमन्माहागणाधिपतये नम: आवाहयमि!

Above lines mean

> Oh great lord Ganapati I summon you!

Also please add the seer of mantra because [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtavinayaka#Varadavinayak) wikipedia article claims that
Sage Grutsmad is seer of this mantra.

> Grutsamad after getting cursed went to the forest of Pushpak and worshipped Ganesha. Sage Grutsamad is famous for the mantra GaNanaN Tva. He founded the temple and called this Ganesha: Varada-Vinayak.

Comment: You shouldn't just say Rig Veda verse 1; that makes it sound as if it's the very first verse of the Rig Veda.  It's Rig Veda Book 2 Hymn 23 Verse 1.

Comment: Why don't you answer this question, I like your views in the comments regarding this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mantra in question is verse 1 of [Rig Veda Book 2 Hymn 23](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02023.htm):

> ghaṇānāṃ tvā ghaṇapatiṃ havāmahe kaviṃ kavīnāmupamaśravastamam |
>
> jyeṣṭharājaṃ brahmaṇāṃ brahmaṇas pata ā naḥ ṣṛṇvannūtibhiḥ sīda sādanam ||
>
> We call thee, Lord and Leader of the heavenly hosts, the wise among the wise, the famousest of all, the King supreme of prayers, O Brahmaṇaspati: hear us with help; sit down in place of sacrifice.

Now at first glance, this might seem like a mantra to Ganesha, since it contains the word "ganapatim", and Ganapati is a name of Ganesha because he's the leader of Shiva's Ganas.  And indeed, this is what has led a lot of people in modern times to recite the mantra as an Ahavana mantra to Ganesha.  But this is actually a mantra to Brihaspati, as you can see in the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36) and [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/QWop) from Shaunaka's Brihaddevata.

You see, the Sanskrit word "gana" has two meanings: it can refer to Shiva's Ganas, but it can also mean group or multitude.  It is in the latter sense that Indra and Brihaspati are called Ganapati; they are leaders of the group of gods.  In any case, it is clear from the rest of the hymn that it's referring to Brihaspati.  In particular, here is what verse 18 says:

> tava śriye vyajihīta parvato ghavāṃ ghotramudasṛjo yadaṅghiraḥ |
> indreṇa yujā tamasā parīvṛtaṃ bṛhaspate nirapāmaubjo arṇavam ||
>
> The mountain, for thy glory, cleft itself apart when, Aṅgiras! thou openedst the stall of kine.
> Thou, O Bṛhaspati, with Indra for ally didst hurl down water-floods which gloom had compassed round.

Brihaspati is referred to as "aṅghiraḥ" because he's the son of the sage Angiras, as I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3106/36).  So it's overwhelmingly clear that this is a hymn to Brihaspati.

Now as far as the seer goes, Wikipedia is right that it's Shaunaka's father Gritsamada; again see the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36).  And it's true that the story of the [Varada Vinayaka](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varadvinayak) temple involves Gritsamada praying to Ganesha.  But as far as I know, there's no scripture that connects the "gananam" verse to either Ganesha or to the story of the Varada Vinayaka temple.  And considering that Shaunka was the son of Gritsamada, he would presumably have accurate information about who his father's hymns were addressed to, so Shaunaka's Brihaddevata is pretty conclusive here.

As far as Vedic mantras to Ganesha go, there are no mantras to Ganesha in the Samhitas or Brahmanas of the Vedas. This is for much the same reason that there are relatively few Vedic hymns to gods like Vishnu and Shiva.  It is because, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36), gods like Indra, Agni, Vayu, Surya, Chandra, etc. have more Vedic hymns dedicated to them, not because they're superior to Vishnu, Shiva, Ganesha, etc., but rather because they play a bigger role in the Soma Yagna.

But as I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8059/36), there is a mantra to Ganesha given in the Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad, the famous Mahaganapati mantra.  The seer of this mantra was the sage Ganaka, whom I suspect was an incarnation of Ganesha just like the sage Narayana was an incarnation of Vishnu, but I'm not sure about that which is why I asked [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8059/36).  In any case, you can call the Mahaganapati mantra a "Vedic" mantra, but there's reason to believe that the Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad is a later interpolation, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3012/36).

Or if you want to settle for Puranic mantras to Ganesha, the Narada Purana has a whole chapter full of them, for instance the famous Vakratunda mantra I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8083/36).  (Of course, there's a possibility that the Narada Purana chapter is also an interpolation, because references to Ganesha in ancient Hindu scripture are few and far between, since he only became popular later on.)

Comment: Can you explain further about jyeṣṭharājaṃ brahmaṇāṃ? Does this word  jyeṣṭharājaṃ indicates Brihaspati or Brahma, as eldest one among REALISED ONEs may indicate him?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv "jyeṣṭharājaṃ brahmaṇāṃ" just means the foremost king of prayers.  It has nothing to do with realized ones.  Jnana is mainly discussed in the Upanishads, not in the actual Samhitas of the Vedas. And yeah, it definitely indicates Brihaspati, as both the Rig Veda Anukramani and Shaunaka's Brihaddevata confirm.  Brahma isn't mentioned that much in the Samhitas of the Vedas; more hymns are dedicated to gods like Indra, Agni, Surya, Chandra, etc. because of the bigger role they play in the Soma Yagna.  It's the same reason why Vishnu and Shiva aren't mentioned that much.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv You're welcome.  By the way, I think Brahma only has two hymns addressed to him in the entire Rig Veda, Book 10 Hymn 121 and Book 10 Hymn 129.  Vishnu has far more hymns addressed to him; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36 The Vedas call Vishnu "the ancient and the last", "the primeval germ of order", "the most excellent of the gods", the embodiment of the Yagna, and the one whose abode is the highest (paramam padam).

Comment: I have my own reservations on the position of Vishnu, as what you commented here and in other posts on Vishnu, appeared to be skewed.  I will get back to you later.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Well, I suggest you read my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36 That contains a thorough explanation of the history of Vishnu-worship.  I'm surprised that someone named Sriman Narayana has reservations about Vishnu's place!

Comment: I am  in search of Truth. I am  searching with open mind

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan How can you use verse 18 containing anghira to justify verse 1.. These two verses are of two separate devtas... Verse 1, 5,9,11,17 and 19 are only verse of Brahmanspati here.... **Can you equate Marut with Rudra by quoting first 7.59.1-11 and then quoting 7.59.12 and telling here it mentions three eyed god hence Marut is three eyed ?** You are doing similar here.. You are equating verse of Brihaspati and Brahmanspati here... verse of Brahmanspati are 1,5,9,11,17,19 and verse of Brihaspati are 2,3,4,6,7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,18...

Comment: @TejasweePokhrel I'm not simply making a conclusion based on verse 18, I'm also citing the Rig Veda Anukramani.  In any case, Brahmanaspati is simply another name for Brihaspati.  That is why the Rig Veda Anukramani lists the Devata for all the verses of this hymn as Brihaspati.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan I think your anukramani is flawed... I have a Sanskrit version of Rigveda with anukramani of every verse... It separates Brihaspati and Brahmanspati there... and further Brihaspati and Brahmanspati can never be same...If they were same they would not have different name... They are just similar.. Brihaspati is simply an aspect of Brahamanspati just like Rudra is just an aspect of Shiva.. applying vyakaran on both name they have same starting root word **bri** which means large, expanding... but brihat becomes an aspect of brahman as brahman is the greatest..

Comment: @TejasweePokhrel The only way to see which Anukramani is right is to refer to the original Sarvanukramani of Katyayana: http://www.dli.ernet.in/handle/2015/486865 I can't read Devanagari script, so please tell me what it says.  In any case, Brihaspati isn't an aspect of Brahmanaspati, rather Brihaspati and Brahmanaspati are just different names of the same god; there are plenty of Vedic verses that call Brahmanaspati the son of Angiras.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan ok I will download and see that...

Comment: Devta of this mantra is Brahmanaspati, According to Mudgal Puran, Brahmanaspati is one of the name of Bhagwān Ganesha.