# Is Rishi Vishvamitra the one who cognised the Gayatri mantra?

Tags: rig-veda, rishi, gayatri-mantra, vishwamitra

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvamitra) wiki article says this without providing any reference:

> *Brahmarshi Vishvamitra* is one of the most venerated rishis or sages of
>   ancient times in India. He is also credited as the author of most of
>   *Mandala 3* of the *Rigveda*, including the *Gayatri Mantra*.

Is there any scriptural reference available for this?

Comment: More appropriate word would be Seer or Rishi of the mantra not author because Shruti's are authorless, and they are seen by rishis in deep meditation

Comment: @Yogi: Okay, noted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Gayatri]Scriptual refrence is itself mentioned in Rig Veda. The Anukramani of Rig Veda gives the name of Sage to which mantra was revealed. Gayatri mantra is in 3.62.10 of Rig Veda and Anukramani mentions it's **Rishi is Vishwamitra.**

As you can see in the image at left top corner **Vishwamitra** is mentioned as the Rishi.

To know what does an Anukramani of Veda mean see question here:
[Is the Anukramani index of sages and deities of the Rig Veda available online?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/is-the-anukramani-index-of-sages-and-deities-of-the-rig-veda-available-online)

Comment: oh okay, could you talk a bit more about what is anukramani in the answer?

Comment: @Amit Saxena Ok! I have added it..

Comment: Wow, so this also shows that the Rishis gave importance to indexing

Comment: @AmitSaxena You may be intrested in my question here http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/why-is-rig-veda-book-2-hymn-23-verse-1-not-used-for-summoning-or-praying-to-shri/8581#8581 related to anukramanika or index of rigveda , and btw there are two types of Indexing in Rig Veda.

Comment: @Amit Saxena Yes, It is interesting...

Comment: @Yogi personally I believe that mantra can still be used for Lord Ganesh if we go by Jnana Kanda Marga...