# What is scriptural source for the Madhwas' claim that Lord Vayu took avatar as Lord Hanuman in Ramayana and again as Bhima in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, hanuman, dvaita, madhvacharya

Madhwas claim a unique thing which as far as I know, no other Hindu denomination claims explicitly that

1. Lord Vayu was first born as Lord Hanuman to serve Lord Rama in Treta Yuga.
2. Lord Vayu was then born as Bhima to serve Lord Krishna in Dwapara Yuga.
3. Lord Vayu was then born as Sri Madhwacharya to serve Lord Veda Vyasa in Kali Yuga.

> The first Avatar of Sri Vayu is Hanuman, son of Anjana Devi. His
> wonderful feats and service to Lord Rama are described in the
> RAMAYANA.
>
> प्रथमो हनुमान् नामा द्वितीयो भीम एव च |
> पूर्णप्रज्ञः तृतीयस्तु भगवत्कार्य साधकः ||
>
> Prathamo Hanuman Nama Dwiteeyo Bheema Eva cha |
> Poornapragna Treetiyastu Bhagavat Karya Sadhakaha ||
>
> The second Avatar is Sri Bhimasena. In Dwapara Yuga, Sri Vayu Deva
> appeared as Bhimasena and played the most important part in the
> destruction of the enemies of God. In the entire Mahabharata,
> Bhimasena played the most important role. He is the one who never
> slipped from the path of righteousness and served Sri Krishna.
>
> Thus, he served God as Hanuman in Ramayana, as Bhima in Krishnavatara
> and, as Madhwa, served Lord Vedavyasa Devaru. He is the greatest
> spiritual benefactor of mankind. This, in short, is the story of
> Avtara Traya - the three avatars of Lord Vayu.

[Source](http://www.vyasamadhwa.org/origin.htm)

---

What is the scriptural source for 1 and 2? And is there any scripture which predicts 3?

Scriptures here means authentic Hindu scriptures like Vedas, Agamas, Smritis, Puranas, Ramayana, Mahabharata and Bhagavad Geeta which are ancient.

Comment: You title and Q description doesn't match...Why title doesn't mention Vayu?

Comment: @YDS isn't it inferred?

Comment: How can Hanuman be "re-born" as Bhima when he himself meets him in the Mahabharata?

Comment: @Vivikta Hmmm like an Avatara??

Comment: Yeah, that's plausible. But, personally I have observed that the scriptural citations used by Anandatirtha aka Madhavachrya are generally obscure and hard to locate in the currently extant texts, if any.

Comment: @Vivikta I will edit it accordingly. The obscure part is because some of the Puranas which were available to him may have gone missing.

Comment: @Vivikta but the Madhwas have some citation wright?

Comment: Can't be sure. As I already said, with Madhavachrya I personally finds obscurity in the citations, mostly. I'll see, If I can find something and try to answer this, if possible.

Comment: @Vivikta thanks

Comment: can't close due to open bounty but this is duplicate of 1. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24527/12304 2. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49889/12304 3. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17404/12304

Answer (score 0):

Balitha Sooktha of Rig Veda 14.12 mandala cites 3 avataras of Vayu, One Hanuman as rtasya dhena ananyatya sushruta.. rta is ram dhena gave message of rama to sita gave happiness to sita and returned the message from sita to rama

Spatishivasu matrsu. He is expert in seven system of vedic knowledge (4 vedas, 2 puranas and  pancharatra vidya) that is bhima

dasapramatim explicit refers to Madhva charya as madhva as called as daspramatim. According Madhva Dasa - Fullness -poorna. Pramatim - consiousness -pragnya. Madhva first named as Poorna Pragya Full consiousness of lord veda vyasa or narayana.  In fourth verse it stats matrishva (who moves in sky i.e. vayu) as matha yathi. one who is sanyasi of particular order refers to madhava.

> > balittha tad vapusedhayi darsatam devasya bhargah sahaso yato ajani |

> > yadimupahvarate sadhate matir-rtasya dhena anayanta sasrutah || 1 ||

> > prkso vapuh pitumannitya asaye dvitiyamasaptasivasu matrsu |

> > trtiyamasya vrsabhasya dohase dasapramatim janayantayosanah || 2 ||

> > niryadim budhnanmahisasya varpasa isanasah savasa krantasurayah |

> > yadimanupradivo madhva adhave guhasantam matarisva mathayati || 3 ||

> > prayatpituh paramanniyateparyaprksudho virudho dansu rohati |

> > ubhayasya janusam yadinvata adidyabistho abhavadhdhrna sucih || 4 ||

> > adinmatrravisadyasva sucirahimsyamana urviya vivavrdhe |

> > anuyatpurva aruhastanajuvoni navyasisva varasu dhavate || 5 ||

The above words and translation is as per madhva interpertaion.

Comment: Can you please add the Standard translation along with Madhwa traditional translation