# How do Vaishnavites understand the Rudrahṛdayopaniṣad?

Tags: shiva, vaishnavism, upanishads, translation-request

- How do Vaishnavites understand the *Rudrahṛdayopaniṣad*?

An [English translation](http://www.astrojyoti.com/rudrahridayaupanishad.htm) of this *upaniṣad* says: “Rudra is the embodiment of all devas. All devas are merely different manifestations of Sri Rudra Himself. Rudra is the generator of the seed. Vishnu is the embryo of the seed. The root is Lord Shiva. The effect is Vishnu. The action is Brahma. The cause is Shiva. For the benefit of the worlds, Rudra has taken these three forms.”

How do Vaishnavites reconcile these words with their own faith, and what other parts of Hindu scripture do they use to do so? Specifically, I am asking about a *Dvaita* conception of this *upaniṣad* that does not generally allow for something like the concept of the *trimūrti* or the idea that all the devas are aspects of *Brahman* (so please don’t give these answers).

**UPDATE:** I would very much appreciate it also if you could link me to a word-by-word or line-by-line translation of the original Sanskrit version of the *Rudrahṛdayopaniṣad*. If you know (enough) Sanskrit and can do translate it word-by-word or line-by-line, that would be perfect! I have also found the [original Sanskrit version](http://www.shaivam.org/sanskrit/ssurudrahridaya.pdf) of the *Rudrahṛdayopaniṣad* so you can use that. Specifically, I want the lines that I quoted above translated from original Sanskrit version word-by-word.

Comment: Truth can be true without revealing actualy truth. Vedas can call any X - god Supreme, not mentioning any God Y anywhere, still Y can turn out to be the supreme without losing authentication of the eternal Vedas. Better you try to find a truth by yourself than parroting. If can't find the truth- adopt a philosophy which makes you harmonious with the nature or with the creations around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same question was asked, on [this Vaishnavaite](http://narayanastra.blogspot.in/p/the-absurdity-of-shakta-interpretations.html)  website. I am just reproducing the same answer that was provided there.

Rudra Hridaya Upanishad is inauthentic because it contradicts many statements in the Vedas that declare Mahavishnu as supreme and aprAkRta (eg., Narayana Upanishad, Mahopanishad, Subala Upanishad, Narayana Suktam, Purusha Suktam, etc. etc.). This also contradicts many statements in the two itihAsas -- Srimad Valmiki Ramayana and Mahabharata -- where there are innumerable statements of Vishnu's supremacy over Brahma and Siva.
We can reinterpret these same “Upanishads” in a manner that actually refutes their opinions!

Note: These Upanishads are indeed bogus and must be discarded as pramAna. We are only interpreting them as a establishment of our stance and to close off these arguments once and for all. That way, even spurious texts will not be used to give distorted meanings of shAstra.

“aa umaa saa svaya.n vishhNuh |” (text “Rudra Hridayopanishad” 1:05)

Shaiva/Shakta interpretation: “Uma Herself is in the form of Vishnu”

Vaidika Interpretation: Fame or Yashas (Uma) is verily VishNu. “Uma” means “yashas” and is the ability to grant brahmAnandam or the ability to mingle with those lesser than himself.

sarvadevaatmako rudraH sarve devaaH shivaatmakaaH .
rudrasya dakshiNe paarshve ravirbrahmaa trayo.agnayaH .. 4..(text “Rudra-ridayOpanishad”)

Vaidika Interpretation: Narasimha who is the destroyer of the disease of samsara (Rudra) is the inner self of all the devas, and the devas are always immersed in bhakti (of nArAyaNa) of an auspicious nature (shivAtmaka). On his left (skilful) side are the Sun like eye, the quality of greatness (Brahmatva) and Sacrifice symbolised by the three agnis.

Purusha Sukta says “ahO rAtrE pArshvE” – day and night are at his sides. In other words, bhagavAn nArAyaNa reconciles contradictions. He has both grace and anger, a snake and an eagle as his servants, etc.

So, here, the mantra describes his two sides. Starting with dakShina pArshvE, it talks about his three characteristics by which he is terrifying to the asurAs. “DakshiNa” means left, but also means “skilful”, so it could be a play on how his actions are both potent and skilful. The 3 characteristics of “vinAshAya ca duskrtAm” are:

His sun like eye that is full of anger against hiranyakasipu.

His brahmatva or absolute supremacy which frightens the asurAs and enables him to punish them.

His actions, signified by sacrifice, that destroy the asurAs. BhagavAn’s deeds are often referred to as sacrifice, tapas, etc in the shAstra. Because his acts are a means by which he saves his devotees, just as yajna is a means to an end.

vaamapaarshve umaa devii vishhNuH somo.api te trayaH
yaa umaa saa svaya.n vishhNuryo vishhNuH sa hi chandramaaH (text “Rudra-HridayOpanishad”)

Vaidika Interpretation: On his right (auspicious) side, there is Lakshmi who possesses the fame (of quenching his anger), his all-pervasiveness (by which he appeared in the pillar instantly to save prahlAda) and the nectarine auspicious attributes (somA). The fame (of sousIlyam or granting brahmAnandam) is verily vishNu and this vishNu is verily lustrous (as a result of this).

This is his graceful side. “vAma” also means auspicious or beautiful and hence once again is a play on words. The 3 attributes are:

Lakshmi, who suggested PrahlAda pacify Narasimha and thus saved the worlds from his anger.

His all-pervasiveness by which he appears swiftly at the call of his devotees.

His nectarine auspicious attributes. Soma is a name of vishNu as per the sahasranAmA (sOmapO amrtapa sOmaH). “Uma” means yaShas or fame. It refers to his guNam of mingling with others lesser than him or granting brahmAnandam. “ChandrAmso” occurs in the sahasranAmA and refers to his lustre.

yo rudraH sa svayaM brahmaa yo brahmaa sa hutaashanaH
brahmavishhNumayo rudra agniishhomaatka.n jagat.h .(text “Rudra-HridayOpaniShad”)

Vaidika Interpretation: Which Rudra, well-known in the sAstra as Narasimha, is verily the Veda (signified by Brahma), which Supreme Brahman (Brahma), well-known in the sAstra as Narasimha, is verily of the form of fire (ie, jwAla narasimha). This rudra (destroyer of the disease of samsara) possessor (maya) of “VishNuBrahma”, ie, the jivAtma whose essential nature is great (brahma) due to possession of 8 auspicious qualities beginning with apahatapApma and whose attributive knowledge is all-pervasive in mOksha (vishNu). The Universe is verily full of sacrifice of the form of “nama:” salutations to Brahman (agni) and objects of enjoyment such as  long age, wealth, etc (sOmA), which are required for upAsaNa.

BrahmI, Brahma, etc are names occurring in the sahasranAma and Parasara Bhattar’s interpretation for these names were used here. The first “Brahma” refers to the Veda. BrahmI means “he who possesses all that goes by the term brahman – prakrti, purusha, ishvara, jivA, etc and this name is used to interpret “brahmavishNu maya” here.

rudramagnimayaM vidyAdviShnuH somAtmakaH smritaH
agnIShomAtmakam chaivA jagatsthAvara jangamam (HarivamSha 2-125-35)

Meaning: Know that Rudra is full of (ie, immersed in) the sacrifice ie, meditation, offerings of “nama:”salutations and remember that vishNu is of the nature of nectar, ie, characterised by auspicious attributes (sOmAtmaka) to be meditated on by upAsakAs like Rudra. The Universe is verily full of sacrifice of the form of “nama:” salutations to Brahman (agni) and objects of enjoyment such as  long age, wealth, etc (sOmA), which are required for upAsaNa.

umA shankarayOgO yaH sa yOgO vishNuruchyatE..( text “Rudra-HridayOpanishad”)

Interpretation: By the meditation (yogO) of his own fame, ie, the sousIlya guNa of mingling with others lesser than himself (umA), (the desire) to perform auspicious acts for his devotees and destroy asurAs (shankara), VishNu delights the jivAs (uchyatE) with (such a nature) of being the definite and indestructible means to liberation (sa yOga).

vyakta.n sarvamumaaruupamavyakta.n tu maheshvaram. (text “Rudra-HridayOpanishad”)

Vaidika Interpretation: All the forms (of bhagavAn) that are manifest (vyaktAn) are of the form (ie, manifestations of his) fame, ie, sousIlyam, desire to mingle with others lesser than himself (umA). nArAyaNa who is the Lord of the Worlds (mahEshwara) is called avyakta because in his avatArAs, his true nature is not manifest to everyone.

**========================**

**Added on 06 Feb 2015:**

**========================**

Please refer to the ["Rudra" debate](http://narayanastra.blogspot.com/p/sankarshana-narasimha-worshipped-by.html)

I also got the following information from  a brilliant, well versed and well learnt Sri Vaishnava.

The narasimha tApanIya Upanishad contains the following enlightening statement:

rudra-japaka-shatam ekam ekena atharvashirah-shikha-adhyapakena tatsamam atharvashirah- shikha-adhyapaka shatam ekam ekena tapaniyopanishad adhyapakena tatsamam tapaniyopanishad-adhyapaka-shatam ekam ekena mantraraja-adhyapakena tatsamam (~Narasimha pUrva tApanIya upanishad).

This says that the mantrarAja pada stOtram is superior to japam of the Rudram, Atharvashika, Atharvasiras and the Narasimha tApanIya itself. This is similar to “srI rAma rAma rAmEti…” in the sahasranAma, which asserts that all the kalyAna guNams described in the sahasranama can be seen in the name of rAma itself. It does not mean the other portions are inferior, but only means that the mantra rAja pada stOtram is the essence of these portions just as “rAma nAmam” is the essence of sahasranAma.

The above part of Narasimha Purva Tapaniya has been accepted by Advaitins also, and a commentary ascribed to Shankara exists.

Maheshvara Tirtha, an ancient advaitic commentator on Sri Ramayana has interpreted "rudrAya vapuShaye" as a pointer to narasimhAvatAra, while explaining the Aditya Hridayam as a Vishnu-stuti (and not a stuti on sUrya as popularly held today).

And advaitins including Shankara, Sureshvara, etc. have interpreted shvetAshvatara upaniShad in a Vaishnava manner only, and that this shvetAshvatara itself contains mantras from Rudram.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You said that you got this from a Vaishnavite website. Would you mind sharing that link with me please?

Comment: You say that the Rudrahrdayopanishad is inauthentic because it contradicts the Itihasas. Yet the Rudrahrdayopanishad belongs to the list of 108 Upanishads in the Muktikopanishad. These Upanishads are considered smrti, while the Itihasas are considered sruti. Aren't the Upanishads more authoritative than the Itihasas? In other words, why should we rule out the statements of the Upanishads rather than ruling out the statements of the Itihasas when there is a contradiction?

Comment: All upanishads that are quoted in muktitopanishad are not valid. Had it been so, prachina vedantins, before 16 th century would have extensively quoted from them. Also, my understanding is, that even, shaiva acharyas before 15th-16th century haven't quoted from these so called Upanishads. So, these upanishads can safely be considered as inauthentic. But, these can still can be interpreted in accordance with Vaishnavism . There appears to be lot of interpolation even in name of upanishads, too. I have added the link from where this information is sourced. Please check that site for more info

Comment: "sarvadevaatmako rudraH sarve devaaH shivaatmakaaH . rudrasya dakshiNe paarshve ravirbrahmaa trayo.agnayaH .. 4..(text “Rudra-ridayOpanishad”)

Vaidika Interpretation: Narasimha who is the destroyer of the disease of samsara (Rudra) is the inner self of all the devas, and the devas are always immersed in bhakti (of nArAyaNa) of an auspicious nature (shivAtmaka). On his left (skilful) side are the Sun like eye, the quality of greatness (Brahmatva) and Sacrifice symbolised by the three agnis." The website translates "Rudra" as "Narasimha." What?! Could you explain this?

Comment: @Aditya - You need go into etymological meaning of Rudra which applies to Narasimha perfectly...rudrah - a) One who brings tears to the eyes. (Prahalda eugolises Lord Narasimha with joy )
>        b) One who confers the good on the devotees (Prahalada episode)
>  c)  One who destroys misery (Lord Narasimha destroyed Hiranyakasipu and destroyed the misery of Prahalada and all other devathas)
>
>Om rudrAya namah
>
> rOdayati iti rudrah - Sri Parasara Bhattar interprets this to mean that He brings tears of joy to the eyes of His devotees.

Comment: @Aditya - The gist of this reference is that one who is not shedding tears of joy on hearing of bhagavAn's guNas, singing His praise etc., must indeed have a heart made of stone.  The reference given is MB 3.3.24.  

It could also mean that He brings tears to the eyes of the beings when He withdraws them during the pralaya. 

Sri Sankaracharya points out that it could also mean one who confers (ra) the good (rud), or it could mean one who destroys (dru) misery and its cause (ru - duhkham) - rum drAvayati iti rudrah. 
All, these are perfectly applicable to Lord Narasimha.

Comment: @Adity a - Please refer to the link i have provided. It should provide you the answer and if required you ask a question to understand the meaning on that web site. They should be able to help you further.

Comment: "Rudra" is a personal name. Through the Vedas, Rudra specifically refers to Rudra/Shiva, not Narasimha. What other scripture refers to Narasimha as Rudra?

Comment: @Aditya- Rudra is not personal name. Rudra, Shiva, Bramha etc are all common nouns as per panini grammar...Rudra refers to Narasimha/Narayana only. Not only SrivAishnavas but even madhvacharya explains that Rudra is actually applicable to Narasimha. Please refer to Narasimha tapani upanishad which indicates the same....If you need any further clarification please raise your query on narayanastra blog spot. They should be able to provide mote details.

Comment: @Aditya : I have further substantiated the answer and provided links to the answers. Please check the updated answer under the section "Added on 6 Feb 2015". Hope it helps

Comment: Whenever the Rigveda refers to "Rudra," then, does it ALWAYS refer to Narasimha? How do you know whether "Rudra" refers to Narasimha or Shiva?

Comment: @Aditya No, it doesn't always refer to Narasimha.  If you want to find whether Rudra refers to Shiva or not in a particular verse of the Rig Veda Samhita, look in the Rig Veda Anukramani (index) given in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36 That will tell you which god a given verse is addressed to.

Comment: @Aditya For instance, consider Book 7 Hymn 59 Verse 12, which is the Mahamrityunjaya Mantra: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07059.htm Now click on the anukramani for Rig Veda Book 7 in my answer, and you'll see that hymn 59 verse 12 is addressed to Rudra, meaning Shiva (since the Anukramanis always use Rudra as a proper name, not a common noun).

Comment: @Keshav - Can you please explain how Rudra is proper noun? Can you please show it refers to parvati pati explicitly? Externally, it may appears as Rudra or parvati pati but the antaryami of this Rudra is Narayana as per Mahopanishad vakyas etc. Hence, it has to understood that the ultimate Supreme Lord Narayana is praised even through all this

Comment: @Krishna When I say Rudra is being used as a proper noun, I'm not making any grammatical point, I'm just saying that references to Rudra in the Anukramani refer to Shiva.  The Anukramani isn't concerned with epithets; it's a simple factual document that refers to different gods by their most recognizable appellations.  Now you're right that in a deep sense, Vishnu is the soul of all the gods, so in that sense all the verses of the Vedas ultimately praise Vishnu.  But the Anukramani just discusses who the hymn is addressed to in a more shallow sense (what you call externally).

Comment: Could you kindly specify where this statement can be verified in the works of Shankara and Sureshwara: //And advaitins including Shankara, Sureshvara, etc. have interpreted shvetAshvatara upaniShad in a Vaishnava manner only, and that this shvetAshvatara itself contains mantras from Rudram.// regards

Comment: The attempt to appropriate the name 'Rudra' to mean Narasimha, etc. can be successful only and only when the Vaishnavas have composed stutis to Vishnu by naming him Rudra, Shiva, etc. without any mixture of Vishnu, Keshava, etc. Also the epithet 'Vaishnava', if also interspersed with the epithet 'Shaiva', by them to refer to themselves.  In the case of Madhwas, if they declare 'Rudra Sarvottama' (instead of Hari Sarvottama), then such claims of 'Rudra is actually Narasimha' can be accepted by Vedantins. Contd..

Comment: contd from previous comment:  In fact there are innumerable Upanishads like Atharva Shikha,  Atharva Shira, Shvetashwatara, Kaivalya, Rudra Hrudaya, Brihad jabala, etc. that unambiguously hold Rudra to be the Para Brahman, Jagat kAranam.  It is only those who are concerned about these Upanishads contradicting their doctrine that attempt to do such 'conversions' of the Upanishads. Vedantins alone, who have not based their doctrine on a deity, are free from any fear of being contradicted by any Upanishad.