# Who was Budha-Kaushika?

Tags: rama, rishi, stotra

One of the many popular Mantra/Stotra in Hinduism is Ram-Raksha Stotra.
And as per this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra) Link, it is written by Budha-Kaushika Rishi.

In Ram-raksha itself, it is mentioned that Lord Shiva told बुधकौशिक about writing the Ram-Raksha:

> आदिष्टवान् यथा स्वप्ने रामरक्षामिमां हर: ।
> तथा लिखितवान् प्रात: प्रबुद्धो बुधकौशिक:

> > (Meaning): This protective hymn of Rama, as told by Shiva (Hara) in the dream । **Was written down** (as told) by the enlightened (by Shiva's visitation) **Budhakoushika** in the morning (upon waking up)

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra)

But beyond this, I could not found much info about this sage.

Is there any scripture that describe about the Life of Budha-Kaushika Rishi and his relation/devotion to Lord Rama or Ramayana?

Comment: I'm not sure who Budha Kaushika is, but it looks like the Rama Raksha stotra is found in the Padma Purana: https://books.google.com/books?id=R51OEErb9g8C&lpg=PA187&dq=%22budha%20kaushika%22&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false By the way, Kaushika means that he's a patrilineal descendant of Vishwamitra, but considering that something like one seventh of all Brahmins are patrilineal descendants of Vishwamitra, that's not saying much.

Comment: My first thought when I saw the name Budha is that it referred to the god of the planet Mercury, but that Budha was the son of Chandra and the grandson of Atri, not Vishwamitra, which is why he's listed as Budha Atreya and Budha Saumya in the Anukramani for Rig Veda hymns V.1 and X.101: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2429/36 So Budha Kaushika is probably a different figure.

Comment: I found the Padma Purana chapter containing the Rama Raksha Stotra: http://gdurl.com/zvPc It doesn't mention Budha Kaushika or Shiva.  It says "the great sage Visvamitra is the seer of the hymn called Ramaraksha", which is interesting given that Kaushika means "descendant of Vishwamitra".  Then it gives a history of how the hymn was passed down: "This (hymn) was told by Vasishta to his preceptor of the form of Vishnu.  Then from Brahma it came to me [Shiva]; and I told it to Narada.  Narada brought it down among the good people on the Earth."  So Shiva was at least involved in passing it down.

Comment: the Link you gave seems to be about "**Rdmaraksd stotra**". My question is related to **Rama Raksha** whose FULL TEXT can be found Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra

Comment: The fact that it says "Rdmaraksd stotra" rather than "Ramaraksa Stotra" is just an error from the PDF being created via optical character recognition from a physical book; it's often hard for a computer to distinguish an italicized a and an italicized d.  But yeah, looking at the Wikipedia article the two hymns seem to be  different, although they're definitely the same kind of hymn (asking Rama to protect different parts of your body).  So then it's not clear to me what scripture the Rama Raksha Stotra you're referring to is from.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda was born and lived as Budakoushika rushi in ancient history .

Comment: @KumarBN `Swami Vivekananda was born and lived as Budakoushika rushi in ancient history .` Do you have any reference to support this statement?

Answer (score 2):

The only reference I could find about him is that he was a Brahmarshi. This is mentioned on page 513 of 'Bhaaratavarshiya Praachin Charitra Kosh', published by Bharatiya Charitrakosh Mandal, Pune, Maharashtra.
Unless it is a team of Budha and Kaushik Rishis.

Comment: What information do you have in the given book? Please add this in the answer. Otherwise the info is inadequate and looks like a comment.