# Does anyone know about Sage Gritakoushik?

Tags: rishi, ancestry

Because My Gotra is **Gritakousik घृतकौशिक**
I never read about Sage Gritakousik in puranas and scriptures.

Comment: See the question [Who was budha kaushika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/who-was-budha-kaushika)? He is one of the rishi with kaushika gotra. In the same way, Grita Kaushika could be one rishi in the lineage of kaushika gotra.

Comment: @SreeCharan Thanks I read it.Now my question here is "Are Budha Kousika and Grita Kousika the same Sages?"

Comment: Might not be. "budha" means a scholar. It was his title than a name. Ghrita means "ghee".  So his gotra might be Kaushika too. Also there is a possibility that many sages have the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, Ghrita Kaushika is only mentioned in three places in Hindu scripture.  First, he's mentioned in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15063.htm) of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, in the Guru Parampara by which the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad was passed down:

> 22. **Ghritakausika** from Pârâsaryâyana,
> 23. Pârâsaryâyana from Pârâsarya,
> 24. Pârâsarya from Gâtûkarnya,
> 25. Gâtûkarnya from Âsurâyana and Yâska,
> 26. Âsurâyana and Yâska from Traivani,
> 27. Traivani from Aupagandhani,
> 28. Aupagandhani from Âsuri,
> 29. Âsuri from Bhâradvâga,
> 30. Bhâradvâga from Âtreya,
> 31. Âtreya from Mânti,
> 32. Mânti from Gautama,
> 33. Gautama from Gautama,
> 34. Gautama from Vâtsya,
> 35. Vâtsya from Sândilya,
> 36. Sândilya from Kaisorya Kâpya,
> 37. Kaisorya Kâpya from Kumârahârita,
> 38. Kumârahârita from Gâlava,
> 39. Gâlava from Vidarbhî-kaundinya,
> 40. Vidarbhî-kaundinya from Vatsanapât Bâbhrava,
> 41. Vatsanapât Bâbhrava from Pathi Saubhara,
> 42. Pathi Saubhara from Ayâsya Âṅgirasa,
> 43. Ayâsya Âṅgirasa from Âbhûti Tvâshtra,
> 44. Âbhûti Tvâshtra from Visvarûpa Tvâshtra,
> 45. Visvarûpa Tvâshtra from Asvinau,
> 46. Asvinau from Dadhyak Âtharvana,
> 47. Dadhyak Âtharvana from Atharvan Daiva,
> 48. Atharvan Daiva from Mrityu Prâdhvamsana,
> 49. Mrityu Prâdhvamsana from Prâdhvamsana,
> 50. Prâdhvamsana from Ekarshi,
> 51. Ekarshi from Viprakitti,
> 52. Viprakitti from Vyashti,
> 53. Vyashti from Sanâru,
> 54. Sanâru from Sanâtana,
> 55. Sanâtana from Sanaga,
> 56. Sanaga from Parameshthin,
> 57. Parameshthin from Brahman,
> 58. Brahman is Svayambhu, self-existent.
>
> Adoration to Brahman

[Another chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15078.htm) of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad says the same thing.

I'm not sure about the identity of Ghrita Kaushika's guru "Parasharyayana", which means descendant of Parasharaya, where "Parasharya" in turn means descendant of the sage Parashara.  I think "Parasharya" refers to the present Vyasa here, because his guru is listed as Jatukarnya and Jatukarnya was the Vyasa of the previous Mahayuga as you can see in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3618/36).  So just as Drona's son Ashwatthama became the shishya of the present Vyasa and he'll become the next Vyasa, it makes sense that the present Vyasa was a shishya of the previous Vyasa.  In any case, if Parasharya refers to Vyasa, then Parasharyayana would probably refer to Vyasa's son Shuka. But I'm not aware of any scriptures that say that Shuka had a shishya named Ghrita Kaushika.

In any case, one thing we can say about Ghrita Kaushika is that he's a descendant of Vishwamitra, which is evident from his surname but is also stated in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adWE2.jpg) from the Manava Shrauta Sutras:

> The Ghrita-Kushikas have three seer-ancestors.  The hotri says: "O thou, related to Vishvamitra, to Ghrita, to Kushika", the adhvaryu: "Like Kushika, like Ghrita, like Vishvamitra".

Comment: Thanks for the information.Is Ghrita Kousika and Kousika the same Rishi?

Comment: @GokulaKhanal The term Kaushika means descendant of Kusha.  Kusha was an ancestor of Vishwamitra, so Vishwamitra and all his descedants are referred to as Kaushika.  Your ancestor Ghrita Kaushika was one of Vishwamitra's descendants.