# Which all Gods and Goddesses are being referred in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, gods, goddess, vedic-gods

I found that many people get confused between Vedas and Puranas due to the reason that a certain deity is being referred in Puranas/other books but there is no reference of him/her in Vedas. So, I want  to know which all Gods/Demi-Gods/Goddesses,etc are being referred in Vedas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deities is mostly refereed in Samhitas and Brahmanas of Rigveda.

1. From [wikipedia>Hindu deities>Number_of_deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_deities#Number_of_deities):

   > The number 33 is based on a verse in the Rigveda and Brihadaranyaka Upanishad - Chapter 3. which 11 gods each in heaven, on earth and in mid-air. Another verse of the Rigveda states that "3,339 gods have worshipped Agni". The extension to 330 million in popular tradition has been attributed to mistranslation. Another source suggests the number is just "intended to suggest infinity". In the [Brhadaranyaka Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brhadaranyaka_Upanishad) (1.9.1), [Yajnavalkya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajnavalkya) asked how many gods there are, and he answers that there are 303,303. When the question is repeated, he says 33. When the question is repeated again, he says six, and when asked yet again, he answers one. The number 33 according to the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad (1.9.2) consists of eight [Vasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasus), eleven [Rudras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudras), twelve [Adityas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adityas), plus [Indra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra) and [Prajapati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prajapati).
   >
   > [Yaska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaska) in his commentary on the Rigveda states that there are three deities, Agni (in the earth), Vayu or Indra (in the air), and Surya (in the sky).
2. I recommend to visit the full article on [**Rigvedic deities**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigvedic_deities)

   > List of Rigvedic deities by number of dedicated hymns, after Griffith (1888). Some dedications are to paired deities, such as Indra-Agni, Mitra-Varuna, Soma-Rudra, here counted doubly. Vishvadevas (all gods together) have been invoked 70 times.
   >
   > - Indra 289
   > - Agni 218
   > - Soma 123 (most of them in the Soma Mandala)
   > - The Asvins 56
   > - Varuna 46 [1]
   > - the Maruts 38
   > - Mitra 28[1]
   > - Ushas 21
   > - Vayu (Wind) 12
   > - Savitr 11
   > - the Rbhus 11
   > - Pushan 10
   > - the Apris 9
   > - Brhaspati 8
   > - Surya (Sun) 8
   > - Dyaus and Prithivi (Heaven and Earth) 6, plus 5.84 dedicated to Earth alone
   > - Apas (Waters) 6
   > - Adityas 6
   > - Vishnu 6
   > - Brahmanaspati 6
   > - Rudra 5
   > - Dadhikras 4
   > - the Sarasvati River / Sarasvati 3
   > - Yama
   > - Parjanya (Rain) 3
   > - Vāc (Speech) 2 (mentioned 130 times, deified e.g. in 10.125)
   > - Vastospati 2
   > - Vishvakarman 2
   > - Manyu 2
   > - Kapinjala (the Heathcock, a form of Indra) 2
   >     
   >     Minor deities (one single or no dedicated hymn)
   > - Manas (Thought), prominent concept, deified in 10.58
   > - Dakshina (Reward for priests and poets), prominent concept, deified in 10.107
   > - Jnanam (Knowledge), prominent concept, deified in 10.71
   > - Purusha ("Cosmic Man" of the Purusha sukta 10.90)
   > - Aditi
   > - Bhaga
   > - Vasukra
   > - Atri
   > - Apam Napat
   > - Ksetrapati
   > - Ghrta
   > - Nirrti
   > - Asamati
   > - Urvasi
   > - Pururavas
   > - Vena
   > - Aranyani
   > - Mayabheda
   > - Tarksya
   > - Tvastar
   > - Saranyu
3. Also see [Deva(Hinduism)>**Vedic** literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_%28Hinduism%29#Vedic_literature):

   ये देवासो दिव्येकादश स्थ पृथिव्यामध्येकादश स्थ ।
   अप्सुक्षितो महिनैकादश स्थ ते देवासो यज्ञमिमं जुषध्वम् ॥११॥[[20]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_(Hinduism)#cite_note-21)
4. For Devi, Refer [Devi>**Vedic** eriod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi#Vedic_period):

   > The Vedas describes a number of significant goddesses. including [Ushas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushas), [Prithvi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prithvi), [Aditi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aditi), [Diti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diti), [Danu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danu_(Asura)), [Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswati), [Vāc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C4%81c), [Nirṛti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nir%E1%B9%9Bti), [Ratri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratri), [Aranyani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aranyani); and a number of minor ones, including Puramdhi, Parendi, Raka, Dhisana, – hardly mentioned about a dozen times in the [*Rigveda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda), and they all are associated with bounties and riches

Comment: See also the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36