# Word by word translation of Rig Veda

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, translation-request

I am looking for word by word English translation of RigVeda. I have only found the translation by Griffith but it's not word by word translation. Does anyone know of if any such translation exists? It would be of great help to me.

Comment: You can look here: http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda

Comment: *Rig Veda Samhita* by the noted indologist Max Mueller may be of some help.

Comment: It is impossible to find true translations for vedas because many vedic sounds are un-translatable; they are sounds and not necessarily linguistic constructs.

Comment: It may help to check the publications of [SAKSHI publications](https://vedah.com/publications/). Please share your reviews if you happen to read them. Also, there are some riks translated by Sri Aruobindo "Hymns to the Mystic Fire" and "The Secret of the Veda" [Website](http://incarnateword.in/sabcl )

Answer (score 8):

You can get word by word translation with commentary of Swami Dayanand Saraswati's RigVeda Bhashya in English at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in).

- [Part 1](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-1-of-5)
- [Part 2](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-2-of-5)
- [Part 3](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-3-of-5)
- [Part 4](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-4-of-5)
- [Part 5](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-5-of-5)