# Who is Vata mentioned in this Sama Veda Verse?

Tags: vedas, sama-veda, ayurveda

While reading the translation of **[Sama Veda](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm)**, I came across this verse dedicated to Vata in Part 2 Book 9 Chapter 2:

> 1. May **Vata** breathe his balm on us, healthful, delightful to our heart:
>      May he prolong our days of life!
> 2. **Thou art our father, Vata, yea, thou art our brother and our friend:
>      So give us strength that we may live!**
> 3. **The store of Amrit that laid away yonder, O Vata, in thine home**--
>      Give us strength that we may live!

I am not really sure to whom this hymn is addressed. Is this related to the three doshas mentioned in Ayurveda - Vata, Pitta, Kapha? **Is there any detailed description with meaning of this or any other Vedic verse on Vata that can understand who or what it is?**

Comment: Yeah Vata means Vayu, Pitta means Agni and Kapha is derived from Bhumi. Vata aka Prana Shakti is described in Upanishads number of times.

Comment: Vata corresponds to Mars, Pitta to Sun and Kapha to Moon. As movements of body's air, fire and phlegm in a way is monitored by these 3 solar entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Vaata is wind God Vayu.

Same mantra occurs in the Rigveda and there is a clear indication of the devatas.

[Rigveda Mandala 10 Sukta 186](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10186.htm):

> 1. FILLING our hearts with health and joy, may Vāta breathe his balm on us
>      May he prolong our days of life.
> 2. Thou art our Father, Vāta, yea, thou art a Brother and a friend,
>      So give us strength that we may live.
> 3. The store of Amṛta laid away yonder, O Vāta, in thine home,—
>      Give us thereof that we may live.

The devata of the above sukta as described in the [Anukramani of Rigveda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/5212) is Vayu and rishi is Vatsa Vaataayana

[image: Image showing devata and rishi of Rigveda Suktas]

Further, Hanuman, who is the son of Vayu, is worshipped as follows:

> मनोजवं मारुततुल्यवेगं
>   जितेन्द्रियं बुद्धिमतां वरिष्ठ ।
>   **वातात्मजं** वानरयूथमुख्यं
>   श्रीरामदूतं शरणं प्रपद्ये ।
>
> 1: Who is Swift as the Mind and Fast as the Wind,
>   2: Who is the Master of the Senses, and Honoured for His Excellent Intelligence, Learning and Wisdom,
>   3: Who is **Son of the Wind God** and Chief among the Vanaras (Who were part of the Devas incarnated in the species of the monkeys to serve Sri Rama during His Incarnation),
>   4: To that Messenger of Sri Rama, I take Refuge (by prostrating before him).

Translation from [greenmesg.org](http://greenmesg.org/stotras/hanuman/manojavam_marutatulyavegam.php)

Vata is another name used synonymous to Vayu.

Monier Williams [gives many other meanings](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/awork/apidev/simple-search/v1.0/list-0.2s.html) but Vayu is closer as devatas like Indra, Savitar are praised in the hymn.

Comment: Great learning for the day!