# Is there a list/book of all Mantras, their Rishis/seers & the Dieties corresponding to each?

Tags: mantras, rig-veda, rishi, krishna-yajurveda

Is there a list or collection of all mantras, their rishis & their deities ?

Comment: What do you mean by all mantras?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Anukramani index of sages and deities of the Rig Veda available online?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/is-the-anukramani-index-of-sages-and-deities-of-the-rig-veda-available-online)