# Is a complete count of rigvedic riks by devata available?

Tags: rig-veda, devatas

Deity        ┃  No. of Mantra  ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃   Agni          ┃       2013      ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃   Indra         ┃       2862      ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃   Soma          ┃       1775

HSE gives the top three.  Is a complete list available?

Comment: Realated or Possibly Duplicate https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2429

Comment: thank you so much @swiftpushkar